# updating PHP variable in Query string from JS variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to check textbox input against a set of words in a certain order from the database to see if they match. If they do, the user's "quest" will be incremented, which will be sent to the relational database to return a new set of words for that given quest ID. the JavaScript questNum and PHP questNum variables seem to be appropriately incrementing, but the query is not getting the right result sets.

Utilities.js file:

When the page loads, I load the words for the first quest:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(wordsArray, function(key, value) {
        $(".wordBank_Words").append("<div class='bank-word' word='" + key + "' ><b>" + key + "</b>: " + value + "</div>");
    });

    /*If user clicks word in word bank, word is added to text box*/
    $(".bank-word").click(function (event) {
        $('#textBox').val($('#textBox').val() + " " + $(this).attr('word'));        
        //hide word from word bank
         $(this).hide();
    });


    /*If User removes word from text box, add it back to word bank*/
    $('#textBox').on('change', function(){
        var words = $(this).val().split(' ');
        $('.bank-word').each(function(){
           if( words.indexOf( $(this).attr('word') ) !== -1 ){
               $(this).hide();
           }
           else {
               $(this).show();
           }
        });
    });
});

/*Check player sentence input to see if grammar is correct*/
function submitMe() {
    var input = document.getElementById('textBox').value;

    if ($.trim(input) == getSentence(questNum)) {
        $("#responseVerify").html("Great job");
        $("#textBox").val("").trigger("change");
        questNum++;
        $.get("php/Quests.php", { "_questNum" : questNum},
            function(returned_data) {
                $("#output").html(returned_data);
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        $("#responseVerify").html("Keep going...");
    }
}
```

Quests.php file:

```
<?php
    //if user's input is correct, increment task number
    include 'DbConnect.php';
    $questNumber = (isset($_GET['_questNum']) ? ($_GET['_questNum']) : 1);  

    echo "testing..." . $questNumber;

    $sql = $mysqli->query(
     "SELECT t.*, v.* 
     FROM task t 
     INNER JOIN vocabtask vt ON (t.id = vt.taskid)
     INNER JOIN vocab v ON (v.id = vt.vocabid)
     WHERE vt.taskid = " . $questNumber);
    $wordsArray = array();               
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $wordsArray[$row['chinese']] = $row['english'];
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);  

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var wordsArray = " . json_encode($wordsArray) . "; </script>";
?>
```

Before the user enters the correct sentence into the text box, `echo "testing..." . $questNumber;` gives output:

```
testing...1
```

When the user enters the correct string into the text box, the JS variable `questNum++;` is incremented, and then `echo "testing..." . $questNumber;` gives output:`

```
testing...2
```

So I know that the incremented JS `questNum` is being sent to the PHP file...

Yet the query `WHERE vt.taskid = " . $questNumber);` doesn't seem to be returning the appropriate new sets of words.

DB is set up as such, so I would expect that the new relational set for the new quest number would be displayed, but it's the same set of values.

[image]

So why isn't the query being changed?

Thanks

---

**EDIT: Echoing out the sql gives:**

1) Before I increment the questNum:

`SELECT t.*, v.* FROM task t INNER JOIN vocabtask vt ON (t.id = vt.taskid) INNER JOIN vocab v ON (v.id = vt.vocabid) WHERE vt.taskid = 1`

2) After I increment the questNum:

`SELECT t.*, v.* FROM task t INNER JOIN vocabtask vt ON (t.id = vt.taskid) INNER JOIN vocab v ON (v.id = vt.vocabid) WHERE vt.taskid = 2`

I copied both of these into phpMyAdmin with success:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the entire query being produced

Comment: @AndyGee what do you mean?

Comment: If the problem is the query, have a look at the query. Use a database tool like phpmyadmin to get the query right and then incorporate the query into your code.

Comment: @AndyGee why, do you see an issue with my query? I don't think there is one

Comment: Your problem is (in your words): The query doesn't seem to be returning the appropriate new sets of words. 
Does the query work in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @Growler if `$questNumber` is giving the correct value, there's probably no point showing your javascript etc. It must be a problem with the php or more likely the sql query. Have you tried, as AndyGee suggested, running the queries directly to see if they work?

Comment: @AndyGee See update. The query works in phpmyadmin

Comment: Echo out the SQL instead of testing 1, testing 2.

Comment: @AndyGee Okay I added it above

Comment: and those queries (if copied) work in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes, but of course I need to remove the php var `$questNumber`

Comment: Copy the output, not the php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45427/discussion-between-andy-gee-and-growler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    //if user's input is correct, increment task number
    include 'DbConnect.php';
    $questNumber = (isset($_GET['_questNum']) ? ($_GET['_questNum']) : 1);  

    echo "testing..." . $questNumber;
    $sql_str = "
     "SELECT t.*, v.* 
     FROM task t 
     INNER JOIN vocabtask vt ON (t.id = vt.taskid)
     INNER JOIN vocab v ON (v.id = vt.vocabid)
     WHERE vt.taskid = " . $questNumber";
    $sql = $mysqli->query($sql_str);
    $wordsArray = array();
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $wordsArray[$row['chinese']] = $row['english'];
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);  
    echo json_encode($wordsArray);
?>

function submitMe() {
    var input = $("#textBox").val();

    if ($.trim(input) == getSentence(questNum)) {
        $("#responseVerify").html("Great job");
        $("#textBox").val("").trigger("change");
        questNum++;
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/Quests.php",
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET",
            data: {"_questNum":questNum},
            success: function(result){
                $.each(result, function(key, value) {
                    $(".wordBank_Words").append("<div class='bank-word' data-word='" + key + "' ><b>" + key + "</b>: " + value + "</div>");
                });             
            }
        });
    }else {
        $("#responseVerify").html("Keep going...");
    }
}
```